# Sql query on taking the value from a case within select statement in a CTE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL. In this, I want columns Bank, and Y-Bank in the output. Y-Bank is being calculated based on certain case statements, using CTE, but I am not able to return Y-Plant as the column.

[image: This is the sample input and output]

I also created a table as shown in the input/output here:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=749e4ca1570880e9c64c4553d18dea1a

Below is the code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
"BANK",
(select 
case 
when "TEST"=0 AND "TEST1">0
THEN ( SELECT COUNT("ZONES")FROM mytable I WHERE  I.BANK = O.BANK AND I."ZONES"='Y' )
END AS "Y-BANK"
from(
  
 (SELECT  
         
          CASE WHEN ( (SELECT COUNT("ZONES")FROM mytable I WHERE I.BINDER = O.BINDER AND I."ZONES"='N' ) = 0 ) AND ( (SELECT COUNT("ZONES")FROM mytable I WHERE I.BINDER = O.BINDER AND I."ZONES"='Y' ) > 0 )
    THEN ( SELECT COUNT("ZONES")FROM mytable I WHERE  I."TOTAL LINE"= O."TOTAL LINE"AND I."ZONES"='N' )
  END AS "TEST",
          CASE WHEN ( (SELECT COUNT("ZONES")FROM mytable I WHERE I.BINDER = O.BINDER AND I."ZONES"='' ) = 0 ) AND ( (SELECT COUNT("ZONES")FROM mytable I WHERE I.BINDER = O.BINDER AND I."ZONES"='Y' ) > 0 )
       THEN ( SELECT COUNT("ZONES")FROM mytable I WHERE  I."TOTAL LINE" = O."TOTAL LINE" AND I."ZONES"='Y' )
  END AS "TEST1"
  from mytable )
  )
  )
FROM mytable O
)
 


SELECT *
FROM CTE O
```

Can someone help me out on how can I correct it?

Comment: Please update the question with an example of desired result and some test data to test on

Comment: Yes,its updated

Comment: What is your output? Please enter

Comment: I am unable to get it. The Y-Bank col is not getting returned

Comment: It would be easier for all that you share some sample data and expected output

Comment: I have already attached the links for the table and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of "Y" values for each bank.  You can use a window function:

```
select t1.*, sum(zones = 'Y') over (partition by Bank1) as y_bank
from t1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e18c0b928fc096d9969dfd1fe3fd9ba) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query

```
select 
   bank1 as "bank",
   (select count(*)over(partition by Bank1,Zones order by Bank1 desc) as "y_bank" from t1 where Zones = 'Y' and Bank1 = t.Bank1 limit 1) as "y_bank"
from t1 t
```